# Error "invalid use of non-static member function" : Results depend on compiler / OS?

Tags: c++, linux, static-methods, msys2

With the MCVE below, when I compile source `classes_test.cc` with

```
$ c++ --version
c++.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0
$ c++.exe -Wall -Wunused -Wuninitialized -g -o classes_test classes_test.cc -std=c++17
```

under Windows 10 + Msys2 (without option `-std=c++17` I get the same), I get the expected results

```
$ ./classes_test.exe
Using GNU G: True
Prototype of BaseClass::get_bc() is int (BaseClass::*)()
```

When I try the same in g++ under Ubuntu, I get compilation error

```
$ c++ --version
c++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
$ c++ -Wall -Wunused -Wuninitialized -g -o classes_test classes_test.cc -std=c++17
classes_test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
classes_test.cc:63:83: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int BaseClass::get_bc()’
  63  | aseClass::get_bc()" << " is " << type(BaseClass::get_bc) << endl;
      |                                                  ^~~~~~
```

**How can the difference be explained?**

**How can I make code work, consistently in both Linux and Msys2?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct BaseClass {
  public:
    explicit BaseClass() : _baseClass_int(0) {};
    explicit BaseClass(const int bci) : _baseClass_int(bci) {};

    ~BaseClass() {};

    int get_bc() { return _baseClass_int; }
    void set_bc(const int bci) { _baseClass_int = bci; }
  private:
    int _baseClass_int;
};

#ifdef __GNUG__
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <string>
#define USING_GNUG  ("True")

std::string demangle(const char* name) {

    int status = -4; // some arbitrary value to eliminate the compiler warning

    // enable c++11 by passing the flag -std=c++11 to g++
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };

    return (status==0) ? res.get() : name ;
}

#else
#define USING_GNUG  ("False")

// does nothing if not g++
std::string demangle(const char* name) {
    return name;
}

#endif


template <class T>
std::string type(const T& t) {

    return demangle(typeid(t).name());
}

int main() {

    cout << "Using GNU G: " << USING_GNUG << endl;
    cout << "Prototype of " << "BaseClass::get_bc()" << " is " << type(BaseClass::get_bc) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to form a pointer to the function, ie: `type(&BaseClass::get_bc)`

Comment: @NathanOliver - Silly me!! Sure!

Answer (score 6):

The code is ill-formed, but MinGW enables some Microsoft-style extensions by default.

Compile with `-fno-ms-extensions` to fix that.

Comment: Very useful. I have added a reference in my own answer, which provides a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per [comment by Nathan Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896347/error-invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-results-depend-on-compiler#comment125333152_70896347), the correct argument for `type` is `&BaseClass::get_bc`.
With that, code works fine.

Plus, as [mentioned by HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70896364/2707864), the way to force Msys2 to report the error (instead of being permissive) is by adding flag `-fno-ms-extensions` to the compilation line. Note that this does not fix the problem.